# built-in inline styles, how do I forcefully change them?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a template that uses bootstrap and jQuery, and I want to customize it. Since it uses jQuery, I **think** that might have to do with the problem I am facing. I usually divide my question into 2 perspectives.

User's Perspective:

The user sees an ugly `h1` line-height, and wants the developer to change it. The `h1` looks squished, and the line height needs to be removed. It looks like this.

[image]

Do you see how the description looks squished?

I want it to look like this.
[image]

Developer's perspective:

The developer (me) is about to go crazy because he has tried the following:

1. Setting an inline line-height style
2. Using an Angular directive
3. playing a bit with jQuery (although I am very new to it)

I also just learned `data-*` attributes in HTML. The devTools looks a bit weird as there are many `data-*`

DevTools:

```html
<div _ngcontent-ng-c801146963="" id="slide-1-layer-2" data-x="['right','left','center','center']" data-hoffset="['65','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-0','-80','30','0']" 
data-fontsize="['60','60','60','30']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2300;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:right;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;"
 data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="750" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" class="tp-caption slide-text-two tp-resizeme" style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap; font-family: &quot;Roboto Condensed&quot;, sans-serif;
 line-height: 16px; visibility: inherit; transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 33px; min-height: 0px; 
min-width: 0px; max-height: none; max-width: none; opacity: 1; transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;">

   <h1 _ngcontent-ng-c801146963="" appresponsivedirective="" id="lineHeight" style="line- 
   height: 14px; transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; border-width: 0px; 
   margin: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 
   15px;">fitness is not a destination it is a way of life
   </h1>

</div>
```

As you can see, `line-height` in the `h1` is 14px and as you will see in the app.html, I didn't set it to 14px.

app.html:

```html
<!-- SLIDE  -->
<li data-index="rs-1" data-transition="slideoververtical">
    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
    <img src="../assets/assets/images/bg/bg-1.jpeg" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>

    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
    <div class="tp-caption slide-text-one tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-1" data-x="['right','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['65','100','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-100','-145','-60','-100']" data-fontsize="['inherit','20','20','17']"  data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:right;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 5; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; line-height: 30px;">
        <h1 appResponsiveDirective id="lineHeight">muscle <span>powerssss</span></h1>
    </div>

    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
    <div class="tp-caption slide-text-two tp-resizeme" id="slide-1-layer-2" data-x="['right','left','center','center']" data-hoffset="['65','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-0','-80','30','0']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','30']"  data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="x:[-100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2300;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:right;y:0;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="750" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; line-height: 30px;">
        <h1 appResponsiveDirective id="lineHeight" >fitness is not a destination it is a way of life</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
    <div appResponsiveDirective id="lineHeight" class="tp-caption rev-btn white-btn" id="slide-1-layer-4" data-x="['right','left','center','center']" data-hoffset="['65','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','bottom','bottom']" data-voffset="['100','160','320','200']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-style_hover="c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bc:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);" data-transform_in="y:bottom;s:1200;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[175%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-start="1250" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-164","delay":""}]' data-responsive_offset="on" data-responsive="off" style="z-index: 8; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 18px; line-height: 15px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 30px;">learn more
    </div>
</li>
```

As you can see, I didn't set any `lineHeight` in the `h1`.

Now, with the fact that this template is using jQuery and Bootstrap, does anyone have a rough idea about what's going on as in why is it giving me automated built-in styles?

Comment: Just copying your code examples on a webpage does not replicate the issue you are seeing. I don't think it's the line-height though, as line-height in itself cannot 'squish' text like that.

Comment: I don’t understand the two ids in the layer 3, nor how two elements appear to have the same id (lineheight). Is that your code?

Comment: In general, Templates work.  If the `<h1>` is misbehaving then it is more likely that your own CSS has redefined some style causing it to "squish".  It may just be a matter of getting out of your own way

Comment: @user3302090 https://github.com/yousefmarey12/womengym , feel free to take your time. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @RenevandenBerg https://github.com/yousefmarey12/womengym , in case you want to look at the code, feel free to take a look at it.

Comment: @AHaworth it is my code, but i understand that it is not very clean.

Comment: @fnostro , well when I look at the DevTools, I see that element has it's own inline styles. Nothing to do from any class or ID.

Comment: This question is not one even people well versed in HTML, jQuery, CSS, and Bootstrap will be able to answer, because it depends on whatever tool you are using that transforms the HTML you have written into the HTML you get rendered. That may very well be written in jQuery, but without seeing its code we can only guess what it does.

Comment: Try some debugging. Make your code so it is  ‘legal’ HTML ie not more than one id of the same value, then use your browser devtools to see exactly what CSS is being applied and from where.

Comment: @IssacHoward - _Something_ is affecting the `h1` styling be it inline or otherwise. The browser Dev tools allows you to play with the styling. Start removing/disabling rendered css until you find the css that affects the `h1` tag